# Why overriding of clone() is required in either shallow copy or deep copy.Can't we write any method (method name) for the same purpose

Tags: java, deep-copy, cloning, shallow-copy

I really don't understand the use of overriding the clone().In case of both shallow and deep cloning we can write any method name and it can serve the purpose.Also we are not using the parent(Object) reference to call the clone method .Then whats the use of overriding please explain.

**Shallow Copy**

```
    class Person implements Cloneable {
    private String name;

    protected Object copy() {//method name is copy
        try {
            return super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

public class TestClone {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person ob1 = new Person();
        ob1.setName("Bibhu");
        Person ob2 = (Person) ob1.copy();
        System.out.println(ob1.getClass() == ob2.getClass());//true
    }

}
```

**Deep Copy**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Company {
    private String name;
    private List<String> empList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Company(String name, List<String> empList) {
        this.name = name;
        this.empList = empList;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<String> getEmpList() {
        return empList;
    }

    public Object copy() {
        List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : this.empList) {
            tempList.add(s);
        }
        String cName = this.name;
        return new Company(cName, tempList);

    }

}

public class TestDeepClone {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> empList = new ArrayList<>();
        empList.add("Bibhu");
        empList.add("Raj");
        empList.add("John");
        Company c1 = new Company("ABC Company", empList);
        Company c2 = (Company) c1.copy();
        System.out.println(c1.getClass() == c2.getClass());//true
        System.out.println(c1.getEmpList() == c2.getEmpList());//false
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just for convention. Even the JavaDoc sais that:

> By convention, classes that implement this interface should override
>   Object.clone (which is protected) with a public method. See
>   Object.clone() for details on overriding this method.